# Install Magento2 Enterprise on desktop Mac via Docker

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise, localhost, docker

I am trying to install a fresh install of Magento2.3.3 enterprise on my local Mac desktop via docker.I am new to docker so maybe i am missing something.

I installed composer, and also docker.

The error i am getting says

```
 To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the 
 https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
 Could not open input file: /app/bin/magento

 An error has occurred. Removing newly installed files and/or Docker containers.
```

I tried manually creating a composer.json file and putting the below in it

```
{
    "require": {
       "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.3"
    }
 }
```

I also made sure my yml file has my correct Magento public and private keys. I am using the tutorial here 
https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento2-freebies/magento2-docker-vm-script/

Also when I run the following command
docker-compose up

I get a error that says
Error: No such object: Websites

Comment: [According to Shawn Abramson](https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento2-freebies/magento2-docker-vm-script/#comment-168) who wrote the `magento2-install` script, he replied, "Hi Mike, it sounds like your Magento files are not mounted to the /app directory inside of the `web` container. Run this command on your mac and see if where your files mount to. The command is: `docker inspect web`." He also wrote another similar blog too but it can happen there too if the conditions are right https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/docker-magento-2-development/